Vaadin Java blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
I've set up a REST controler in my Vaadin Java Spring Boot app. For every @GetMapping endpoint I create, everything works fine, but for @PostMapping I always get this error from Angular:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at <my_page> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
When I create a new spring boot app from scratch, it works, but in my current vaadin app it just doesn't. Can someone help please, I'm stuck.
Here is my REST code:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*") // Allow requests from any origin
public class RESTController {
    

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @PostMapping("/print")
    public Map<String, Object> printMessage(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) {
        System.out.println("Received JSON: " + payload);
        payload.put("status", "Received successfully");
        return payload;
    }
}

My SecurityConfiguration:

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration
        extends VaadinWebSecurity  {

    @Autowired
    CrmService crmService;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/jobs/images/**"), // Allow public access to images
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/getfields/**"), // Allow public access to /api/getfields/**
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/images/*.jpg"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.png"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.jpg"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.svg"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.css"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.ts"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.js"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.html")
                )
                .permitAll());
        
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);

        http.headers(headers -> headers
                .contentSecurityPolicy(csp -> csp
                        .policyDirectives("frame-ancestors 'self'")
                )
        );
        super.configure(http);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        // Customize your WebSecurity configuration.
        super.configure(web);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService(crmService);
    }

}

WebConfig:
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .maxAge(3600);

                registry.addMapping("/api/getfields/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .maxAge(3600);

            }
        };
    }


I tried changing parameters of SecurityConfig and WebConfig, but nothing worked.

Since you're configuring CORS globally, you don't need the @CrossOrigin annotation on your controller.
 @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class RESTController {
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @PostMapping("/print")
    public Map<String, Object> printMessage(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) {
        System.out.println("Received JSON: " + payload);
        payload.put("status", "Received successfully");
        return payload;
    }}

Make sure that CORS configuration is properly integrated with Spring Security.
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity  {

    @Autowired
    CrmService crmService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Apply CORS configuration
        http.cors().and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers(
                    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.png"),
                    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.jpg"),
                    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.svg"),
                    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.css"),
                    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.ts"),
                    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.js"),
                    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**/*.html")
                ).permitAll()
            );

        super.configure(http);

        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);

        http.headers(headers -> headers
            .contentSecurityPolicy(csp -> csp
                .policyDirectives("frame-ancestors 'self'")
            )
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Customize your WebSecurity configuration.
        super.configure(web);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService(crmService);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}

Make sure CORS mappings are configured correctly:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}


I get an error for this line "http.cors().and()", from your code, that these methods are deprecated. I can't run it.
